# How to hide radio_button and use a div/label as the button instead? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radio-button

In a simple_form I'm trying to style the radio_buttons.

But how do I hide the radio_buttons and select a table_id by clicking on the label?

```
  <% Table.all.each do |rt| %>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
      <%= f.radio_button :table_id, "fd", :id=>"hi-#{rt.id}", :style=>"display:none;" %>
      <label for="hi-#{rt.id}" class="btn btn-primary box3"><%= rt.id %>
      </label>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

**Notes:**

table has_many :reservations

reservation belongs_to :table

table_id is a integer-column in reservations table.

[Screenshot of the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7VcX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer.

View:

```
<% Table.all.each do |rt| %>
  <label class="btn btn-primary box3" for="reservation_table_id_<%=rt.id%>">
    <%= f.radio_button :table_id, rt.id %>
    <span><%= rt.id %></span>
  </label>
<% end %>
```

Style:

```
label > input{
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
label > input + span{
  cursor:pointer;
  border:2px solid transparent;
}
```